# Trying to understand transfering listbox values/items with sessions.

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, listbox, response.redirect

On my first page I have two listboxes for *Movies* and *Snacks*

They are called **lbDisplay** for *Movies* and **lbSelected** for *Snacks*.

I am currently using a "Go to cart" function that has the following code:

```
Session["lbSelectedMovies"] = lbDisplay;
Session["lbSelectedSnacks"] = lbSelected;
Response.Redirect("RingU6POSReview.aspx");
```

on the redirected page the two listboxes that I want the given values to transfer to are called **lbRvMovies** and **lbRvSnacks**

The page is called `RingU6POSReview.aspx`

Can anyone help me understand how to transfer the values when I redirect the customer?

Comment: what is the `Type` of `lbDisplay`...??

Comment: Type? Its a single selection listbox.

Answer (score 0):

On the 2nd page say you have another list box (say ListBox1) to which you want to assign the passed values then use the any one of the foll. 3 methods:

```
   ListBox  ListBox1 = null;

        ListBox1 = Session["lbSelectedMovies"] as ListBox;
```

OR

```
ListBox ListBox1 = new ListBox();       
    foreach (ListItem Item in ((ListBox)(Session["lbSelectedMovies"])).Items)
    {          
        ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(Item.Text, Item.Value));
    }
```

OR

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange((ListItem[])Session["lbSelectedMovies"]);
```

Comment: Would you put this code on the "Go to cart" method on the first page?

Comment: No, this should go on the 2nd page. On the 1st page the code you have mentioned in the question should be enough.

Comment: Would this go in the "SelectedIndexChanged" part of the listboxes on the second page? aka do I double click on the listboxes and input this with those methods?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tag you!