# I am unable to get data from one page to the next in listbox C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, listbox, response.redirect

On my first page I have two listboxes for Movies and Snacks
They are called `lbDisplay` for Movies and `lbSelected` for Snacks.

I am currently using a "Go to cart" function that has the following code:

```
Session["lbSelectedMovies"] = lbDisplay;
Session["lbSelectedSnacks"] = lbSelected;
Response.Redirect("RingU6POSReview.aspx");
```

on the redirected page the two listboxes that I want the given values to transfer to are called `lbRvMovies` and `lbRvSnacks`

The page is called `RingU6POSReview.aspx`

Can anyone help me understand how to transfer the values when I redirect the customer?

I am taking a data from **"lbDisplay"** that is similar to.... "

> "12 movies at $12.00 each."

and data from lbSelected such as "Snickers" "Twix" etc...

Comment: You have already asked this question just 15 mins back....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474880/trying-to-understand-transfering-listbox-values-items-with-sessions?noredirect=1#comment34188655_22474880

Comment: It wasn't answered correctly and was no long generating any response. I need help!

Answer (score 1):

You can take the Session values as follows...

```
lbDisplay.Text=Session["lbSelectedMovies"].Tostring();
lbSelected .Text=Session["lbSelectedSnacks"].Tostring();
```

Please Mark as answer if it satisfies you..

Comment: Would this be on the initial page or in the page load of the redirected page?

Comment: Sorry,Use this in the redirected page...

Comment: Again, this is wrong. I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In first page , store text of listbox in respective Session variables.

```
Session["lbSelectedMovies"] = lbDisplay.SelectedValue;
Session["lbSelectedSnacks"] = lbSelected.SelectedValue;
```

In second page ,

```
string selectedMovie = Session["lbSelectedMovies"].ToString();
string selectedSnacks = Session["lbSelectedSnacks"].ToString();

lbRvMovies.Items.Add(selectedMovie);
lbRvSnacks.Items.Add(selectedSnacks);
```